# instantiation of a generic tree pointer ada

Tags: pointers, tree, ada, generic-collections

I try to build a generic binary search tree module in Ada, and the tree will be the generic parameter, so, i do that:

```
-- Spécification du module ABR.


-- Mettre T_ABR comme un pointeur générique.
Generic
    type T_Noeud(<>);
        type T_ABR is access T_Noeud; -- Pointeur sur T_Noeud.


package ABR is


    Cle_Presente_Exception : Exception; -- une clé est déjà présente dans un ABR
    Cle_Absente_Exception  : Exception; -- une clé est absente d'un ABR


    -- Initialiser un Abr.  Abr est vide.
    -- Param Abr : L'arbre qu'on va initialiser.
    procedure Initialiser(Abr: out T_ABR) with
        Post => Est_Vide (Abr); -- Abr := Null.


    -- Est-ce qu'un Abr est vide ?
    -- Param Abr : L'arbre qu'on vaudra savoir si elle est vide.
    -- Retrun Boolean : Retourne True si Abr est vide, sinon False.
    function Est_Vide (Abr : T_Abr) return Boolean;


    -- Obtenir le nombre d'éléments d'un Abr. 
    -- Param Abr : L'arbre qu'on vaudra calculer sa taille.
        -- Retrun Integer : Retourne la taille de Abr.
    function Taille (Abr : in T_ABR) return Integer with
        Post => Taille'Result >= 0        -- Retourne une taille positive.
        and (Taille'Result = 0) = Est_Vide (Abr); -- If taille (Abr) = 0 then Abr := Null


    -- Insérer une clé associée à un nouveau noeud dans Abr.
    -- Param Abr : L'arbre où on veut insérer un noeud.
    -- Param Cle : La Clé correspondante au noeud qu'on veut insérer.
    -- Exception : Cle_Presente_Exception si la clé est déjà dans l'Abr.
    procedure Inserer (Abr : in out T_ABR ; Cle : in Integer) with
        Post => Taille (Abr) = Taille (Abr)'Old + 1; -- Un élément de plus.


    -- Supprimer la donnée associée à la clé Clé dans l'ABR Abr.
    -- Param Abr : L'arbre où on veut supprimer un noeud.
        -- Param Cle : La Clé correspondante au noeud qu'on veut supprimer.
    -- Exception : Cle_Absente_Exception si Clé n'est pas utilisée dans l'Abr
    procedure Supprimer (Abr : in out T_ABR ; Cle : in Integer) with
        Post =>  Taille (Abr) = Taille (Abr)'Old - 1; -- Un élément de moins.


    -- Supprimer tous les éléments d'un ABR.
    -- Doit être utilisée dès qu'on sait qu'un ABR ne sera plus utilisé.
    -- Param Abr : L'arbre à détruire.
    procedure Vider (Abr : in out T_ABR) with
        Post => Est_Vide (Abr);


    -- Afficher un ABR Abr dans l'ordre croissant des clés (parcours infixe)
    -- Param Abr : L'arbre à afficher.
    procedure Afficher (Abr : in T_Abr);


    -- Afficher un ABR Abr (en faisant apparaître la strucre grâce à une
    -- indendation et un signe '<', '>', '/' pour indiquer la sous-arbre
    -- gauche, '>' pour un sous arbre droit et '/' pour la racine)
    -- Exemple :
    --
    --  / Cle1 : Valeur1
    --      < Cle2 : Valeur2
    --          > Cle3 : Valeur3
    --      > Cle4 : Valeur 4
    --          < Cle5 : Valeur 5
    -- Param Abr : L'arbre à afficher.
    procedure Afficher_Debug (Abr : in T_Abr);


private


    type T_Noeud is
        record
            Cle: Integer;
            Sous_Arbre_Gauche : T_ABR;
            Sous_Arbre_Droit : T_ABR;
            -- Invariant
            --    Pour tout noeud N dans Sous_Arbre_Gauche, N.Cle < Cle.
            --    Pour tout noeud N dans Sous_Arbre_Droit,  N.Cle > Cle.
        end record;


end ABR;
```

then, I implemented the body of this module in abr.adb:

```
-- Implantation du module ABR.


with Ada.Text_IO;            use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Unchecked_Deallocation;


package body ABR is


    -- Libérer la mémoire.
    procedure Free is
        new Ada.Unchecked_Deallocation (Object => T_Noeud, Name => T_ABR);


    procedure Initialiser(Abr: out T_ABR) is
    begin
        Abr := Null;
    end Initialiser;


    function Est_Vide (Abr : T_Abr) return Boolean is
    begin
        return Abr = Null;
    end;


    function Taille (Abr : in T_ABR) return Integer is
    begin
        if Est_Vide (Abr) then
            return 0;
        else
            return 1 + Taille (Abr.all.Sous_Arbre_Gauche) + Taille (Abr.all.Sous_Arbre_Droit);
        end if;
    end Taille;


    procedure Inserer (Abr : in out T_ABR ; Cle : Integer) is
    begin
        if (Est_Vide(Abr)) then 
            Abr := New T_Noeud'(Cle, Null, Null); 
            elsif (ABR.all.Cle = Cle) then
            raise Cle_Presente_Exception;
        elsif (Cle < Abr.all.Cle) then
                Inserer(Abr.all.Sous_Arbre_Gauche, Cle); 
            elsif (Cle > Abr.all.Cle) then
                Inserer(Abr.all.Sous_Arbre_Droit, Cle);   
        end if;
    end Inserer;


    procedure Supprimer (Abr : in out T_ABR ; Cle : in Integer) is
        tmp1 ,tmp2 : T_ABR;
    begin
        if (Abr = Null) then
            Null;
        else
            if (Cle < Abr.all.Cle) then 
                    Supprimer (Abr.all.Sous_Arbre_Gauche, Cle); 
            elsif (Cle > Abr.all.Cle) then
                            Supprimer (Abr.all.Sous_Arbre_Droit, Cle);
                else

                    if (Abr.all.Sous_Arbre_Gauche = Null) then  
                    tmp1 := Abr.all.Sous_Arbre_Droit; 
                        Free (Abr); 
                            Abr := tmp1; 

                    elsif (Abr.all.Sous_Arbre_Droit = Null) then 
                            tmp1 := Abr.all.Sous_Arbre_Gauche; 
                            Free (Abr); 
                            Abr := tmp1; 
                else 
                    tmp2 := Abr.all.Sous_Arbre_Droit;
                    while (not Est_Vide (tmp2) and tmp2.all.Sous_Arbre_Gauche /= Null) loop
                            tmp2 := tmp2.all.Sous_Arbre_Gauche;
                    end loop;
                    tmp1 := tmp2;

                    Abr.all.Cle := tmp1.all.Cle;
                    Supprimer (Abr.all.Sous_Arbre_Droit, tmp1.all.Cle);
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end Supprimer;


    procedure Vider (Abr : in out T_ABR) is
    begin
        if not Est_Vide (ABR) then
            Vider (ABR.all.Sous_Arbre_Gauche);
            Vider (ABR.all.Sous_Arbre_Droit);
            free (ABR);
        end if;
    end Vider;


    procedure Afficher (ABR : in T_Abr) is
    begin
        if Est_Vide (ABR) then
                Afficher( Abr.all.Sous_Arbre_Gauche);
                Put_Line(Integer'Image(ABR.all.Cle));
                Afficher( ABR.all.Sous_Arbre_Droit);
        end if;
    end Afficher;


    procedure Afficher_Debug (Abr : in T_Abr) is
    begin
        if not Est_Vide (ABR) then
            Put_Line (Integer'Image(ABR.all.Cle));
            Afficher_Debug ( ABR.all.Sous_Arbre_Gauche);
            Afficher_Debug ( ABR.all.Sous_Arbre_Droit);
        end if;
    end Afficher_Debug;


end ABR;
```

And I created a test file for ABR module, but i don't know how i can instantiate the previous module :

```
-- Programme de test du module ABR.


with Ada.Text_IO;          use Ada.Text_IO;
with ABR;                  use ABR;


procedure Test_ABR is


    -- Instantiation du package ABR. 
    package ABR_Test is
            new ABR (T_Noeud => xxx);
        use ABR_Test;


    -- Initialisation des variables.
    Nb_Donnees : constant Integer := 10; -- Taille du tableau Cles.
    Cles : constant array (1..Nb_Donnees) of Integer -- Cles est un tableau 
    := (56, 78, 76, 27, 90, 23, 12, 43, 24, 39);     -- contenant des clés.


    -- Initialise l'ABR Abr commen un ABR vide dans lequel ont été insérées
    -- les cles Cles ci-dessus.
    procedure Construire_Exemple_Arbre (Annuaire : out T_ABR) is
    begin
        Initialiser (Annuaire);
        pragma Assert (Est_Vide (Annuaire));
        pragma Assert (Taille (Annuaire) = 0);

        for i in 1..Nb_Donnees loop
            Inserer (Annuaire, Cles (i));

            Put_Line ("Après insertion de la clé " & Cles (i));
            Afficher_Debug (Annuaire);
            New_Line;

            pragma Assert (not Est_Vide (Annuaire));
            pragma Assert (Taille (Annuaire) = i);
        end loop;

        Vider (Annuaire);
        pragma Assert (Est_Vide (Annuaire));
        pragma Assert (Taille (Annuaire) = 0);

        Put_Line ("Procédure Construire_Exemple_Arbre est exécuté avec succès.");
        New_Line;
    end Construire_Exemple_Arbre;


    procedure Tester_Exemple_Arbre is
        Annuaire : T_ABR;
    begin
        Construire_Exemple_Arbre (Annuaire);
        Vider (Annuaire);
        pragma Assert (Est_Vide (Annuaire));
        pragma Assert (Taille (Annuaire) = 0);

        Put_Line ("Procédure Tester_Exemple_Arbre est exécuté avec succès.");
        New_Line;
    end Tester_Exemple_Arbre;


    -- Tester suppression en commençant par supprimer les feilles.
    procedure Tester_Supprimer_Inverse is
        Annuaire : T_ABR;
    begin
        Put_Line ("Tester_Supprimer_Inverse...");
        New_Line;

        Construire_Exemple_Arbre (Annuaire);

        for i in reverse 1..Nb_Donnees loop

            Supprimer (Annuaire, Cles (i));

            Put_Line ("Après suppression de " & Cles (i) & " :");
            Afficher_Debug (Annuaire); 
            New_Line;
        end loop;

        Vider (Annuaire);

        Put_Line ("Procédure Tester_Supprimer_Inverse est exécuté avec succès.");
        New_Line;
    end Tester_Supprimer_Inverse;


    -- Tester suppression. Suppression de noeuds avec deux fils.
    procedure Tester_Supprimer is
        Annuaire : T_ABR;
    begin
        Put("Tester_Supprimer...");
        New_Line;

        Construire_Exemple_Arbre (Annuaire);

        for i in 1..Nb_Donnees loop
            Put_Line ("Suppression de " & Cles (i) & " :");

            Supprimer (Annuaire, Cles (i));

            Afficher_Debug (Annuaire); 
            New_Line;

        end loop;

        Vider (Annuaire);

        Put_Line ("Procédure Tester_Supprimer est exécuté avec succès.");
                New_Line;
    end Tester_Supprimer;

begin
    Tester_Exemple_Arbre;
    --Tester_Supprimer_Inverse;
    --Tester_Supprimer;
end Test_ABR;
```

Please, help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 4):

You don’t say what the compiler complains about in your code. However, I see something seriously wrong in your design, indicated by the compiler reporting

```
hamza.ada:82:09: generic type cannot have a completion
```

(it’s complaining about the fact that you have a full declaration of `T_Noeud` in the private part of package `ABR`).

Your generic package should take at least a formal parameter (in English, perhaps `Item`) to correspond to the type of object that you want to store in it. You might want to have a formal parameter for equality, typically

```ada
with function "=" (L, R : Item) return Boolean is <>;
```

Your generic package should then declare a public type to  correspond to tree instances, e.g.

```ada
type Tree (<>) is private;
```

(or perhaps `Arbre`) and then in the private part you should declare all the supporting types (`T_Noeud`, `T_ABR`) needed to build `Tree`.

It should never be up to the user of your package to declare the types used to implement the abstraction.

---

Part of the problem instantiating `ABR` in the code as it stands is that the full declaration of `T_Noeud` thoroughly confuses the compiler, to the point where it rejects the instantiation, saying

```
designated type of actual does not match that of formal "T_ABR"
```